# Cómo puedo dar varias funciones a un botón dependiendo del usuario que ingrese al sistema?

Tags: javascript, html

Ya tengo el filtro sobre quien ingresa al sistema y quien no, pero necesito que el botón ejecute funciones distintas dependiendo del usuario que ingresa y el problema que tengo es que el botón que tengo en el html es uno solo y tiene la id de la función que se ejecuta, por lo tanto no puedo darle otra función dependiendo del usuario que ingrese, siempre es la misma función.

Alguien podría darme una idea de como hacerlo?

Por ejemplo si ingresa al sistema el Usuario1 quiero que al presionar el botón1 se ejecute la functionusuario1, pero si ingresa al sistema el Usuario2 quiero que al presionar el mismo botón1 se ejecute la functionusuario2...

Este es el botón

```
<p><button id="btnmasA" onclick="btnmasAClick()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Siguiente</button></p></div></p>
```

Y esta es su función, pero quiero que esa función cambie según el usuario que ingresa.

```
function btnmasAClick() {
  var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    numero = isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero;
    numero++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = numero;
}
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo... Espero puedan ayudarme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas hacer es algo como esto asi que solo implementalo de acuerdo a lo que quieras lograr con el programa.

```
<body>
    <script>
        function f1() {
            console.log("Primera funcion.");
        }
        function f2() {
            console.log("Segunda funcion.");
        }
        function f3() {
            console.log("Tercera funcion.");
        }  
        function funciones(parametro){
            if(parametro == 1){
                f1();
            } else if(parametro == 2){
                f2();
            } else {
                f3();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <p>
        <button id="btnmasA" onclick="funciones(1)">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Siguiente
        </button>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, esto me servirá yo creo... Ahora tengo otro problema jajajaja. Haré otra consulta. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza una sola función para el botón, pero dentro de esta coloca una estructura de selección que permita realizar diferentes acciones según el usuario.

Comment: Esta clase de respuestas serian mas propias de un comentario que de una respuesta como tal de StackOverflow

Comment: Mis disculpas, tengo entendido que los comentarios se utilizan si tengo una duda sobre la pregunta o si no estoy segura de que mi respuesta sea funcional.

Comment: no te preocupes, tambien los comentarios son para dar pequeños consejos como este, para dar una respuesta debe de tener una estructura completa en donde le contestes exactamente lo que esta preguntando junto con un ejemplo de ser posible.

Comment: Muchas gracias ^^